# How to get the value of parameter

Tags: javascript, socket.io

How can I get the value of my parameter to the socket.io server?

In my client I have this simple code:

```
var id = '0001';
var userame = 'Shane';

socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('getdetails', {id:id},{username:username});
});
```

In the server (app.js):

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('getdetails', function (data) {
        console.log(data.username);
    });
});
```

But username is undefined. How to get the value of my username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add user name and id to the data param in the client. 
It looks like when server gets it, data is empty.

Try {id:id,username:username}

Comment: i already have that code, socket.emit('getdetails', {id:id},{username:username});

Comment: I'm not thinking that is attaching it to the data param. I bet on the server, id is also empty

Comment: I bet id is also undefined, no?

Comment: Only the id will display to the server if i console.log(data.id);console.log(data.username); username is undefined

Comment: Well, if you aren't doing anything different for id on the client, then I don't know. Sorry

Comment: Unless you are really ending Shane with a quote. I assume that is just a typo here and not in your code

Comment: you want me to change the variable id to other variable ?...I am confuse

Comment: sending only one parameter like this in my client, socket.emit('getdetails', {id:id}); this works i can receive the value of id in my server(app.js) but i want to have two parameter the problem is that i cannot retreive the value of second parameter

Comment: If you really have ` var userame = 'Shane";` in your code, that quote after Shane is the problem.

Comment: that's error typo, i corrected it now,but still problem is not yet solve

Comment: Try {id:id,username:username}